# The translation of 重ねていた

Tags: translation

> だから僕は、たまに彼を昔の僕と重ねていた。

> 重ねて:
>   1. 同じ行為・事態をもう一度繰り返すさま。再び。文章語で、多く手紙や公式の発言に用いる。 「 －要望する」
>   2. この次。今後。 「 －は泥鰌（どじよう）にてもあれ、鮠（はえ）にても候へ必ず持つて伺候致さうずる／狂言・鱸庖丁」
>   ([Source](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%87%8D%E3%81%AD%E3%81%A6))

The context is the narrator finds his classmate quite similar to his former self. So point 1 fits the above sentence.

Could I translate it as follows:

> That's why I sometimes saw my former self again in him.

Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: Why look up the adverb 重ねて, not the **verb** 重ね**る** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> だから僕は、たまに彼を昔の僕と**重ねて**いた。

重ねて in 重ねていた is not an adverb but the te-form of the verb 重ねる.

Here (～を‥と/に)重ねる means "to identify ~~ with‥" "to see ~~ in‥" (≂重ね合わせる), hence the translation:

> That's why I sometimes **saw my former self in him**.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I'm totally a beginner, even though I have read the te-form, but I still got confused. I'm grateful for your kind explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This 重ねて is a simple te-form of the verb 重ねる, followed by いた that makes the past-progressive form (expresses a past habitual action in this case). Or you can say this is the past-teiru-form of 重ねる. Here, 重ねる means "to identify with someone" or "to project someone into ～".

> だから僕は、たまに彼を昔の僕と重ねていた。
>   That's why I sometimes projected him into my past self.

As you have cited, 重ねて also has a lexicalized usage ("once again"), but you can forget it for now.

Comment: あっ また遅かったぁ～....

Comment: Thank you, I can understand a bit more now. I'm grateful to join this forum, I learned a little by a little.