# Meaning of 重ね in a compound verb

Tags: verbs, definitions, compound-verbs

I'm trying to interpret the sentence

> 笑みを交わしてのひらを重ね信じる

The part that's giving me trouble is 重ね信じる, which is a compound verb that I haven't seen before.

重ね, as the stem form of 重ねる, means a pile or heap of something, while 重ねる means to stack, overlay, or repeat something. I came across [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72263/the-translation-of-%e9%87%8d%e3%81%ad%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f) that gives different answers for the definition, so now I'm more confused on how to read 重ね信じる.

Could it mean to believe in stacking something?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any chance you've got a typo in your sample sentence?  And could you provide any additional context?

Comment: This is the full sentence: 予感の声聞くよりも  そう、笑みを交わしてのひらを重ね信じる

Answer (score 3):

It's parsed [笑みを交わし][てのひらを重ね][信じる].

That て should be 手. Strange that 手 isn't in kanji here; it's a basic kanji and using て really blends it into the previous word, and I misread it the first couple times through.

Anyway, 重ね here is a transitive verb with 手のひら being the object being stacked. I read this as a fancy way to say "hold hands".

Maybe with some poetic license, I'd translate it to something like:

> Smile at each other, put my hand in yours and believe.

*I suspect that was someone typing out the line and forgot to convert the kanji. Does the original song have this as well?

Comment: Yes. Here are the full lyrics on the FF Fandom: [Yuna's Ballad](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Yuna's_Ballad#Lyrics)

Comment: @A.T.A. Ah OK. It must be some sort of stylistic choice, but at least there is a space after 交わし to help readers parse the sentence correctly.

Comment: Can てのひらを重ね信じる be translated as something like, "We smile at each other, while I believe in putting our palms together"? It makes sense as putting one thing on another is basically like putting them together.

Comment: @A.T.A. That would have to be something like 手のひらを重ねることを信じる. I don't see any other way of reading 重ね信じる as "stack, and believe".

Comment: Wouldn't reading it like that be the same as 重ねて信じる?